# Intro to proofs in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Hey I am m having trouble proving this OFC10:

If $x < y$ and $z < 0$, then $yz < xz$.

I started with $x+z < y+0$ by OFC8, but right now I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

Note: OFC10 means Ordered Field Consequence 10.

Comment: Only those using your textbook will know what OFC10 means.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, thanks for that and I have added a little note to my question.

Comment: @Adib "Ordered field consequence 10" is still meaningless to those who aren't using the textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z<0$ means $0<-z$ and $x<y$ means $0<y+(-x)$.

You may want to prove $(-a)b = -(ab), \,(-a)(-b)= ab$ beforehand, but you may also prove them directly in your proof:

The product of two positive numbers is positive, thus

\begin{align} & 0<(-z)(y+(-x)) \\
& = (-z)y + (-z)(-x) \\
\end{align}
You can jump to the last line if you've already proved the aforementioned statements, otherwise:
\begin{align}
& = (-z)y + (-z)(-x) + -(zy) + zy \\
& = y(z+(-z)) + (-z)(-x) + -(zy)\\
& = y\cdot0  + (-z)(-x) + -(zy) \\
& = y\cdot0  + (-z)(-x) + -(zy)+ y\cdot0 + -(y\cdot0) + x\cdot0 + -(x\cdot0) \\
& = y\cdot(0+0) -(y\cdot0)+ (-z)(-x) + -(zy) + x\cdot(0+0) + -(x\cdot0) \\
& = y\cdot0 -(y\cdot0)+ (-z)(-x) + -(zy) + x\cdot0 + x\cdot0 -(x\cdot0) \\
& = (-z)(-x) + -(zy) + x\cdot0\\
& = (-z)(-x) + -(zy) + x(z+(-z))\\
& = (-z)(-x) + -(zy) + (-z)x+zx \\
& = (-z)(-x + x) + -(zy) + zx \\
&= (-z)\cdot0 + (-z)\cdot0 + -((-z)\cdot0) + -(zy) + zx \\
&= (-z)\cdot(0+0)+ -((-z)\cdot0) + -(zy) + zx \\
& = -(zy) + zx
\end{align}

which by definition means, $zy<zx$.

(Note that this proof can be shortened a lot if we already knew $a\cdot0=0$.)

Here, I've used [these axioms](https://www.math.washington.edu/~hart/m524/realprop.pdf) of $\mathbb R$.

Note that $x\in \mathbb {R}^+\iff x>0$. Using the definition of $x>y$ as $x+(-y)\in \mathbb R^+$, this shouldn't be hard to prove.

Comment: You messed up your conclusion.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Yes, I've fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @Alraxite Thanks. The problem for me was to make the right assumptions to start the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x-y < 0$ and $z<0$ then $(x-y)z>\ldots$?

Comment: Why the downvote?